# Manually calculated Adam algorithm diverges

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to perform a linear regression problem by manually performing the Adam algorithm, helping myself with these formulas: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLVuJ.png).
Here's my implementation:

```
def grad(x, y, w, b, par):
  if par == "w":
    return -2*x*y-w*x-b
  if par == "b":
    return -2*y-w*x-b # returns partial derivatives of w or b

# a piece of adam function is obviously cut, def grad is not in the following piece of code

for t in range(epochs):
    if t % sw == 0:
      arr = np.random.randint(0, n, batch_size)
    
    if t % 100 == 0:
      print(w, b)

    for i in range(len(arr)):
      mw = beta1 * mw + (1 - beta1) * grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'w') # first parameter
      vw = beta2 * vw + (1 - beta2) * ((grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'w'))**2) # second

      mmw = mw/(1 - beta1) # m hat
      vvw = vw/(1 - beta2) # v hat

      w = w - (alpha * mmw)/(math.sqrt(vvw)+epsilon)

      mb = beta1 * mb + (1 - beta1) * grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'b')
      vb = beta2 * vb + (1 - beta2) * ((grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'b'))**2)

      mmb = mb/(1 - beta1)
      vvb = vb/(1 - beta2)

      b = b - (alpha * mmb)/(math.sqrt(vvb)+epsilon)
```

However, w and b diverge both to infinity, so I suppose I made some mistake with the formulas. Can someone help me spot those errors out? Thanks

Comment: What are the `mb`, `wb`, etc. calculations? I don't see them in the source provided.

Comment: Wikipedia provides formulas only for one parameter. In case of linear regression, there are two, so formulas are to perform for both parameters

Comment: So both should be equal then.

Comment: No. Partial derivative of the loss with respect to w is different to the partial d. with respect to b

Comment: Worded myself poorly - the _formulas_ should be the same.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what do you mean, i think w and b formulas are the same except for the gradient part. But, as i wrote, I'm not very sure about the validity of those. Could you provide your version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252355/discussion-between-iya-lee-and-b-remmelzwaal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I figured it out.

The errors were 2:

- In the formulas Wikipedia provided, when calculating m and v hats (mmw, vvw, mmb, vvb), the hyperparameters beta1 and beta2 had to be elevated by t+1, so the code became

```
      mw = beta1 * mw + (1 - beta1) * grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'w')
      vw = beta2 * vw + (1 - beta2) * ((grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'w'))**2)

      mmw = mw/(1 - beta1**(t+1))
      vvw = vw/(1 - beta2**(t+1))

      w = w - (alpha * mmw)/(math.sqrt(vvw)+epsilon)

      mb = beta1 * mb + (1 - beta1) * grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'b')
      vb = beta2 * vb + (1 - beta2) * ((grad(x[arr[i]], y[arr[i]], w, b, 'b'))**2)

      mmb = mb/(1 - beta1**(t+1))
      vvb = vb/(1 - beta2**(t+1))
```

- However, the first error did not made the algorithm diverge, it just made it slower. The principal error was in the gradient formula:

for `w`, it is `-2*x*(y-w*x-b)`, for `b`, it is `-2*(y-w*x+b)`.

Comment: Had a suspicion it was there :)